# .mat files as input for caffe deep learning network

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, caffe

Is it possible to use .mat files to store input data for the caffe deep learning framework? if yes, how can I change the 'data' of my train_val.prototxt? I am using the googlenet network.

If no, which other file formats can I use rather than mdb and hd5?

For me, using .mat files is better because of their size, my .hd5 files are huge (caffe can't read them because of lack of memory) and I can't find how to save my data as .mdb files in Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mat files version 7.3 are hdf5 files, just make sure to use this format when writing. (check documenting for save)

Any hdf5 library which supports gzip compression can read mat files.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying to save my matrix as an .hd5 file rather than .mat? only this? or no? in my deep learning configuration file I must inform if my data is hd5 and where it should be read. If .mat files are .hd5 files I can point the address where the .mat file is, right?

Comment: Mat v7.3 is hdf5. Use save or matfile command to write and Amy hdf5 library to read.